# localhost doesnot connect in offline mode?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost, offline-mode

have not tested on windows. but in ubuntu when u disconnect from the network, start ur Apache, and enter localhost in any browser, it does not shows ur localhost page, it is suppose to show.

Comment: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/207456

Comment: Serverfault for sure, also not a question really...

Comment: I think this safely falls under either SO or SF. If closed I'll vote to reopen. Welcome to Stackoverflow Vivek. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. There may be something about your name resolver that works differently when not connected to a network.

Comment: one solution, is to use the browser in offline mode. but that is not a proper solution i think.
do i change something in resolov.conf or hosts files.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/hosts` file to see if `127.0.0.1` has `localhost` as one of its values.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost 
    127.0.1.1 vksTP 
    # this is how the /etc/hosts looks for IPv4

Answer (score 0):

are you using Mozilla Firefox ?
Firefox goes to offline when he is not connected (or disconnected) to network. so check your browser if you are using FF and turn off offline .. then you can go to localhost.